# How to install stuff like Requests and BeautifulSoup to use in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am an extreme beginner with Python and its libraries and installation in general. I want to make an extremely simple google search web scraping tool. I was told to use Requests and BeautifulSoup. I have installed python3 on my Mac by using `brew install python3` and I am wondering how to get those two libraries

I googled around and many results said that by doing `brew install python3` it will automatically install pip so I can use something like `pip install requests` but it says pip: command not found.

by running `python3 --version` it says Python 3.7.4

Comment: Try using `pip3`? Since you're using python3, not 2.

Comment: @PioKozi thank you, i never knew about such small discrepancies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're running with Python3, not Python (which usually refers to 2.7), you should try using `pip3`.
`pip` on the other hand, is the package installer for Python, not Python3.